# How to pass an argument to a form class in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to pass a product id to my form class to create a form with that item in my database.

My form:

```py
class Order_form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, product_id,*args,**kwargs):

        self.add_option = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = False, queryset=product.objects.get(id = product_id).add_option.all())
        super(Order_form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

The form above doesn't create anything but this form is creating exactly what I need. However, I need to pass the `product_id` dynamically, and not have to hardcode `1` as the id:

```
class Order_form2(forms.Form):
    add_option = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = False, queryset=product.objects.get(id = 1).add_option.all())
```

PS: everything is working thanks to answer and comments below now my form looking like that

```
class Order_form(forms.Form):
    add_option = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = False, queryset=None)
    def __init__(self, product_id,*args,**kwargs):
        super(Order_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['add_option'].queryset=product.objects.get(id = product_id).add_option.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is roughly what it should look like.

```
class Order_form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, product_id,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(product_id, *args, **kwargs) # This is the default stuff that forms.Form does

         # You need to add this part so that it edits the field after creation
        self.fields['add_option']= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required = False, queryset=product.objects.get(id = product_id).add_option.all())
        # super(Order_form,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs) this  would re-overwrite it so we don't want it here
```

This is generally how it's done in django.

Comment: you could also set the field queryset in the `views` if you are going to recycle the form in slightly different settings around your app.

Comment: Yup, it is basically `form.fields[field_name] = new_form_field`

Comment: `'int' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: That's a problem with your queryset, it seems that for some reason `product.objects` is None.

Comment: You don't even have to set a whole new `form_field` in `views`.  You can do `form.fields[field_name].queryset = new_queryset`.  I've found that this approach saves me a ton of space.

Comment: I feel like the whole `formsForm` class needs a little new wrapper around these. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: `print(product.objects.get(id = product_id).add_option.all())`
`<QuerySet [<AdditionalOption: 1>, <AdditionalOption: 2>]>`

Comment: ez pz i've replaced your `uper().__init__(product_id, *args, **kwargs)` to my old `super(Order_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` and its working right now